# TCP socket program to send a Buffer.

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

//The below code works fine, but is used to send a string. What changes do I have to make in order to send a buffer (address of the buffer) containing a header with fields of different data type? (I'm new to programming. So, excuse the noob in me)

```
ClientSocket.cpp

ClientSocket::ClientSocket ( std::string host, int port )
{
  if ( ! Socket::create() )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not create client socket." );
}

  if ( ! Socket::connect ( host, port ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not connect." );
    }

}


const ClientSocket& ClientSocket::operator << ( const std::string& s ) const
{
  if ( ! Socket::send ( s ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not write to socket." );
    }

  return *this;

}


const ClientSocket& ClientSocket::operator >> ( std::string& s ) const
{
  if ( ! Socket::recv ( s ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not read from socket." );
    }
  return *this;
}






simple_client_main.cpp

#include "ClientSocket.h"
#include "SocketException.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ( int argc, int argv[] )
{
  try
    {

      ClientSocket client_socket ("169.254.103.63", 30000 );

      std::string reply;

      try
    {
      client_socket << "Test message.";
      client_socket >> reply;
    }
      catch ( SocketException& ) {}

      std::cout << "We received this response from the server:\n\"" << reply << "\"\n";;

    }
  catch ( SocketException& e )
    {
      std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\n";
    }

  return 0;
}




ServerSocket.cpp

// Implementation of the ServerSocket class

#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include "SocketException.h"


ServerSocket::ServerSocket ( int port )
{
  if ( ! Socket::create() )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not create server socket." );
    }

  if ( ! Socket::bind ( port ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not bind to port." );
    }

  if ( ! Socket::listen() )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not listen to socket." );
    }

}

ServerSocket::~ServerSocket()
{
}


const ServerSocket& ServerSocket::operator << ( const std::string& s ) const
{
  if ( ! Socket::send ( s ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not write to socket." );
    }

  return *this;

}


const ServerSocket& ServerSocket::operator >> ( std::string& s ) const
{
  if ( ! Socket::recv ( s ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not read from socket." );
    }

  return *this;
}

void ServerSocket::accept ( ServerSocket& sock )
{
  if ( ! Socket::accept ( sock ) )
    {
      throw SocketException ( "Could not accept socket." );
    }
}




simple_server_main.cpp

#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include "SocketException.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, int argv[] )
{
  std::cout << "running....\n";

  try
    {
      // Create the socket
      ServerSocket server ( 30000 );

      while ( true )
    {

      ServerSocket new_sock;
      server.accept ( new_sock );

      try
        {
          while ( true )
        {
          std::string data;
          new_sock >> data;
          new_sock << data;
        }
        }
      catch ( SocketException& ) {}

    }
    }
  catch ( SocketException& e )
    {
  std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\nExiting.\n";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add new send() and recv() functions, which you have not shown. A socket can send binary data but you have to tell it the size in bytes. On the recv() side there will be an issue figuring out how many bytes you need before you have the entire struct. This usually requires adding some protocol, such as a length prefix to every message.